# Node w/Express MongoDb/Mongoose how to trigger 2nd database request to create an event logger

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to create an event logger system that logs database events, I initially created this system to run on the front end (sending more than one request to the api), but have decided that it would be much better to do this all on the back end. I would like to trigger a 2nd event when a database request is made like when a user creates/modifies/deletes a document, that the system records that event along with some info that goes along with it.

I am struggling with how to add this to my node/mongo api and am wondering what is the best practice. I've read about event emitters, however i'm not sure if this would be the best way to trigger this second event - in addition to that, i'm not sure how to pass info through the emitter to the 2nd mongoose request.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I overlooked the next() command.